# Do we know for sure that laws of physics are time invariant?

Tags: time, symmetry, maxwell-equations

Is there a proof that Maxwell's equations will hold true even billions of years in the future, for example?

Comment: How could you prove this, I mean really prove it...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do the laws of physics evolve?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10078/)

Comment: In general, "absolute certainty" is not a scientific mindset.

Comment: The Maxwell equations come from a combination of the rotational symmetry gauged by the Lorentz symmetry of spacetime (special relativity). So for as long as circles are round and clocks still tick in this universe, the Maxwell equations should hold. (Nice username BTW. Impactful.)

Comment: @safesphere I'm not quite sure what a real proof is, as opposed to a proof. Anyway, have a pleasant 2018.

Comment: @Countto10 You too! :)

Comment: @safesphere Or, there can be some deep variables to screw things up even when circle is round and clocks tick.

Comment: Not likely. The universe is based on very simple basic principles. The complexity comes from these principles interweaving together. It's not just the Maxwell equations. Everything we are and see around (short of gravity) is electromagnetism. And it is all due to the rotational symmetry in spcetime. To change this you'd need something even more foundational meaning even simpler, which doesn't seem to be possible. Short of all universe going into a black hole or something, I wouldn't worry about the future fate of electromagnetism. Also there are no "variables", only our lack of knowledge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a proof that Maxwell's equations will hold true even billions
>   of years in the future, for example?

No.

Comment: I might add here that 1) we currently have no strong evidence in hand that maxwell's equations have changed any time in the past, 2) no plausible and compelling mathematical models which would allow for that and simultaneously furnish an explanation for why the universe at this point in time happens to be the way it is, and 3) no  outstanding unsolved problems which are furnished convincing solutions by changes over time in maxwell's equations.