# How does the fine-structure constant $\alpha$ vary on cosmological scales?

Tags: particle-physics, cosmology, quantum-electrodynamics, physical-constants

The
observations of quasar absorption spectra show that the
fine-structure constant varies on large scales. I know that $U(1)_{EM}$ coupling constant $\alpha$ depends upon the coupling constants of $SU(2)_L\times U(1)_Y$, which vary with energy scale. But at cosmological scales what causes the variation in $\alpha$.

Comment: There is no conclusive evidence that the fine structure constant has ever varied. There is some experimental evidence that it **might** have been different in the past but there is too much uncertainty in the measurements to say this for sure. It would be very exciting if $\alpha$ is definitively proven to have changed because that would be our first real evidence for physics beyond the Standard Model. Sadly we'll have to wait.

Comment: Despite, as John Rennie says, the lack of conclusive evidence, there _are_ several proposed mechanisms for a possible cause. See e.g. Sec 3. in [Bronnikov & Kononogov (2006)](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0604002v3).

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2725/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3607/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @JohnRennie I thought our first evidence of physics beyond the standard model was that things fall down.

Comment: Isn't the existence of massive neutrinos (as in neutrinos possessing a non-zero mass) also evidence of physics beyond the standard model?